# Starting of bash script

Tags: bash, shell, comments

What is reason behind writing

```
#! /bin/bash
```

at the very starting of every bash script ?

I means, I know that it is kind of hack but I want to know how it exactly works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call the script with an explicit interpreter, like

```
 bash foo.sh
 /bin/bash foo.sh
 dash foo.sh
 sh foo.sh
```

your choosen interpreter is used, no matter what the shebang says, which is just a comment.

If you make the script executable, and start it:

```
 chmod a+x foo.sh
 ./foo.sh
```

the kernel looks for the shebang and starts the program with the therein specified interpreter. Since the kernel doesn't know the PATH, the whole path has to be given, or `env` has to be used:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
```

to choose the local path for a program.

Since dash, bash, zsh and so on aren't fully compatible, you should call the program without a specific interpreter, because the author should have known what he does.

Maybe on your system `sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`, but beware! The shell can introspect how it was called, and bash can act in a way, called POSIX mode, which is slightly different and only a subset of what it normally does.

If you write scripts for installation or for servers, which might run on different platforms - think OsX, Linux, Solaris and so on, where different shells are available, you will try to restrict yourself to this subset, to gain a compatible, reusable result.

But on your private machine, you might prefer the more convenient shells like `zsh` and `bash`.

Answer (score 4):

check out shebang!.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (shall I precise that this is not harmful):

- create a new file containing:

  ```
  #!/bin/rm
  whatever
  ```
- set executable bit with `chmod +x the_file`
- run with `./the_file`
- see that your file disappeared magically.

So, as Kent suggests, she-bang in an executable file tells the path to another executable file that will be used as an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Unix doesn't use extensions (.sh, .bat, whatever) to identify file contents.

The "#!" notation ([shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) is a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) used to tell the kernel how to execute a script by providing the path to its expected interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

To invokes the Bourne shell or a compatible shell in your script.

Look: [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)